# use define to generate Makefile rule with eval function

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I want to generate rules in Makefile like this for many PROG

```
CC = gcc
LD = gcc
CFLAGS = -g
LDFLAGS = -g

PROGS = test1 test2

SRCS_test1 = test1.c
SRCS_test2 = test2.c

$(foreach prog, $(PROGS), $(eval OBJS_$(prog) = $(SRCS_$(prog):%.c=%.o)))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(PROGS)

define PROG_template
$(1): $$(OBJS_$$(1))
    @echo ------------------
    @echo $(1)
    @echo $$(OBJS_test1) $$(OBJS_test2)
    @echo $$(OBJS_$(1))
    @echo $$^
    @echo -----------------
    $$(LD) $$(LDFLAGS) -o $$@ $$^
endef

$(foreach prog, $(PROGS), $(eval $(call PROG_template, $(prog))))

%.o: %.c
    @echo compiling $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS_test1) $(OBJS_test2) $(PROGS)
```

the output like this

```
------------------
test1
test1.o test2.o


-----------------
gcc -g -o test1
```

gcc prompt no input file.
what's wrong with my Makefile?
Thanks at first.
Sorry, My English is poor.

Comment: GNU make version 4 is scriptable in Guile. You should consider doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors.  The first is just a typo; this line:

```
$(1): $$(OBJS_$$(1))
```

should be:

```
$(1): $$(OBJS_$(1))
```

(note removing unwanted `$` in the second `$(1)`.

The second error is more subtle: you have to be careful about whitespace when you are invoking functions in make.  When you leave whitespace in arguments to `call`, for example, it can get embedded into the argument.  So here:

```
$(foreach prog, $(PROGS), $(eval $(call PROG_template, $(prog))))
                                                      ^
```

That space is being used verbatim as part of the argument, so `'$1'` is equivalent to `' test1'`, not just `'test1'`.  You can debug `eval` operations by replacing the eval with `info` to see what make sees:

```
$(foreach prog, $(PROGS), $(info $(call PROG_template, $(prog))))
```

will show you:

```
 test1: $(OBJS_ test1)
```

note the extra space.

Remove extra whitespace and it'll work:

```
$(foreach prog, $(PROGS), $(eval $(call PROG_template,$(prog))))
                                                     ^^
```